# loading remote data on server in PHP

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to load content from a remote URL in my php code. There are two restrictions:

1. I need to use the dedicated server IP I have so the REMOTE_ADDR of the other server has to be my dedicated IP. This eliminates Curl because Curl uses a proxy to load the remote URL and the proxy changes the IP address which does not work.
2. I need to load the data on my back-end using PHP. I do not wish to use Javascript for security reasons.

Are there any other solutions other then Curl?

Thank you

Comment: cURL uses a proxy?  Is this something unique to your configuration?

Comment: hi Frank, well the hosting provider uses a proxy on their cloud servers. So when I make a call to cURL it goes out of my server and thru a proxy then to the URL i want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the [stream api](http://docs.php.net/book.stream) and a wrapper that utilizes the socket-wrapper you can set the [bindto context parameter](http://docs.php.net/context.socket) to accomplish (1) :

> Used to specify the IP address (either IPv4 or IPv6) and/or the port number that PHP will use to access the network. The syntax is ip:port. Setting the IP or the port to 0 will let the system choose the IP and/or port.

```
$ctx = stream_context_create( array(
  'socket' => array(
    'bindto' => '192.168.0.107:0',
   )
));

$c= file_get_contents('http://php.net', 0, $ctx);
```

Comment: Using the 'bindto' property was the key to this problem. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

What about `file_get_contents($url)`? Just note that some websites require a user-agent, so you'll have to set one with `ini_set()` before making the call.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably use [fopen](http://nadeausoftware.com/articles/2007/07/php_tip_how_get_web_page_using_fopen_wrappers) for this.

Comment: +1 Yup, and if fopen_url_wrappers isn't enabled, there's always the lower level socket functions.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

```
<?php
$homepage = file_get_contents('http://www.stackoverflow.com/');
echo $homepage;
?>
```